# $.goMap Plugin: Can I create a link to 'Directions' based on marker lat & long?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm loading markers based on lat & long (stored in database for each location).

In the popup info window for each marker, it'd be neat to have a link to directions on the full google map website. Can I generate the link just based on the lat & long?

(I do also have the street, subrub etc for labeling the info window)

EDIT: link to plugin http://www.pittss.lv/jquery/gomap/

Comment: does plugin support google maps directions service queries? Post link to docs for plugin

Comment: http://www.pittss.lv/jquery/gomap/

Comment: suggest using a plugin with better API and documentation... try Gmap3. Easy to integrate directions and documentation and features are far more robust

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer as no, at least not in an automatic way with this plugin.